# Problem with adding a file to Mendix as a attribute

Tags: file, upload, mendix

Good afternoon,

I have a little problem in which I can't find a solution to.
For a school project, I need to create an application. The main goal of this app is to give an organization the opportunity to store PDF files in this app (meaning they can upload files from their computer into this). I'm using Mendix to create this app and have the following problem: When I try to create a file upload button, I keep getting errors and I don't know how to fix it. Do you know how to upload files in a Mendix container in an easy way? Thanks in Advance. I've already created an entity relationship diagram.

Answer (score 0):

There's a component in the Mendix Marketplace that could help you. The name is
[FileDropper](https://marketplace.mendix.com/link/component/111497).
In addition, there's also a [Git Repository](https://github.com/mendixlabs/mendix-file-dropper) where you can find detailed instructions and a Sample project.

Good luck!